# Как протестировать данный метод?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, testng, mockito, mock

Есть класс, методы которого необходимо протестировать. Собственно проблема: не могу правильно mock'нуть объекты тестируемого класса для покрытия метода тестом.

Метод класса, который необходимо протестировать.

```
public List<FileInfo> getAllFileInfos(Path dirPath) {
if (!Files.exists(dirPath)) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      getLocalizedMessage("dir_not_exists", dirPath));
}
Stream<Path> pathStream = Arrays.stream(getArrayOfPaths(dirPath))
    .map(fileName -> dirPath + fileName)
    .map(Paths::get);
  return pathStream
      .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().equals(metaInfoFileName))
      .map(this::getFileInfosFromMetaInfo)
      .flatMap(List::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList()); } 

public String[] getArrayOfPaths(Path dirPath) {
File directory = new File(dirPath.toString());
return directory.list(); }
```

Подскажите, что мне следует сделать дальше? Как mock'нуть Stream и его методы?

Comment: будьте добры, укажите код кодом, а не картинкой.

Comment: что именно в этом коде вы хотите протестироовать? Какую логику? Если вы тестируете возможность чтения папки с файлами, то тут нет вашей логики, это всё делает машина / SDK за вас.

Comment: Я хочу протестировать следующую логику:
при передаче в данный метод пути на определенный файл, метод должен возвращать определенную информацию об этом файле.

Comment: зачем это тестировать? Вы же не вручную эту информацию получаете? Ну или покажите этот метод в вопросе.

Comment: По Вашему мнению, данный метод не требует наличия тестов?

Comment: Если он занимается чисто вызовом системных функций типа получения списка файлов или получения аттрибутов файла, то вы в своем тесте будете тестировать системные функции, что само по себе смысла не имеет.

Comment: Вы, наверное, правы, это не так необходимо, как я посчитал ранее. Спасибо !

Comment: на здоровье. Оформил ответом

Answer (score 3):

Если метод занимается чисто вызовом системных функций типа получения списка файлов или получения атрибутов файла, то вы в своем тесте будете тестировать системные функции, что само по себе смысла не имеет как минимум по нескольким причинам:

1. Внешние библиотеки уже должны быть протестированы производителем, то есть писать на них тесты - это двойная работа
2. Внешние библиотеки не относятся к коду проекта, потому тесты внешних библиотек не проверяют качество кода в вашем проекте
3. Падение тестов внешних библиотек вы не решите изменением своего кода, если вы по прежнему будете пользоваться тем же функционалом библиотеки
4. Для проверки работоспособности всей системы в целом (в том числе интеграции вашего кода между собой и внешними системами), существуют интеграционные тесты

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно мокать `Arrays.stream`. Можно в unit-тестах воспользоваться правилом [`TemporaryFolder`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html)

```java
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder tmpFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void yourTestWithoutMocks() {
    <prepare tmpFolder, add files, add folder into it>
    List<FileInfo> infos = getAllFileInfos(tmpFolder.getRoot().toPath())
    <assert your infos>
}
```